# Not receiving proper data when routing as asterisk *

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to define my **'/'** route as **'*'** because I am using **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);** in Angular.

By defining my main route as an **asterisk** my website keeps it's state when refreshing. Otherwise it gives a "CANNOT GET" error if I am refreshing for e.g. on the **/login** page.

But when I define my main route as an **asterisk** it doesn't receive the proper data from the server.

**get '*'**

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./index');
});

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.json({go : 'Welcome to the test page.'});
});
```

Gives:

```
Object { data: "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" ng-…", status: 200, headers: wd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }
```

^ Which is the whole **index** template.

**get '/'**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./index');
});

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.json({go : 'Welcome to the test page.'});
});
```

**Gives**

```
Object { data: "test", status: 200, headers: wd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }
```

By calling a button with this function in **Angular**:

```
my.test = function() {
      $http.get('/test')
        .then(handleSuccess)
        .catch(handleError);

        function handleSuccess(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
        function handleError(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Also: When I use the **asterisk** it doesn't matter if I do the api call in Angular to e.g. **/sdkjfkwjfk** because it always sends the **index** template as data.

Comment: @dan Nope doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the controller with the asterisk at the end:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.json({go : 'Welcome to the test page.'});
});

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./index');
});
```

or otherwise the other controllers will never get called.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately this isn't working.

Comment: It is working. I had changed the client-side code for testing and didn't change it back. Thanks.